# Asp.Net Web Api: Parameter on controller is null, model not being populated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a standard class with 1 property on at the moment

```
public class RangeProperties
{
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
}
```

This is entered onto a controller as an argument, like so

```
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetItems(RangeProperties rangeProperties)
```

I have set a breakpoint in the controller so I can see that it enters but rangeProperties is always null.

I am calling the controller like so

```
   http://localhost:8383/api/GetItems?ItemNumber=test
```

I have tried updating the ItemNumber as an int and int? still nothing. I have tried different cases too.

I would have expected that the rangeProperties would not be null.

I was hoping to have rangeProperties to hold a number of properties and then these properties would be populated from the querystring, if I didn't send something down then the property inside would be null.

But currently its not even working with even 1 property.

Anybody know what I am doing wrong ?

Although i am working with asp.net web api, i believe this also is similar to asp.net mvc.

1 thing worth noting is that if I replace the controller with (string itemNumber) it works. But for complex types it isn't autopopulating.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetItems([FromUri]RangeProperties rangeProperties)
```

By default, Web Api reads simple types in the request's querystring, and complex types in the request's body. In your case, you try to pass a value for a complex type in the querystring, so you have to force web api to get `RangeProperties` values from the querystring using the `FromUriAttribute`.

The opposite attribute is the `FromBodyAttribute`, in case you have an int or string value in a post request's body.